# Can we get a "Favorite Site" link box somewhere?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks, stack-exchange-button

Hi! I hope this is the correct place to ask this. I primarily use stackoverflow.com and programmers.stackexchange.com . I'd love to have maybe a dropdown at the top of the page in the menubar of my "Favorite Sites" that I could define in my profile somewhere. I hate having to scroll to the bottom, and then find that the site I want isn't even there. Just a thought, I'm sure a lot of people would consider it useful.

Comment: Maybe even just a Favorites item in the StackExchange dropdown box?

Comment: Maybe even just an auto generated most used site list under a favorites / recent menu, just so we can have a list, and avoid using preferences? I saw in another thread Jeff doesn't like preferences, so an auto list would help solve that, I'd think.

Comment: And why does the All Sites option seem to randomize every time??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We now **sort the gen-u-wine sites list by the amount of reputation you have on each site.**

[image]

You must have a minimum of **200 rep** on any given site to have it appear in anything other than random order, though.

Comment: Great idea! Very unobtrusive.