# The gen-u-wine sites list is not sorted by reputation total on StackExchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, stackexchange.com

[According to Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72438/can-we-get-a-favorite-site-link-box-somewhere/74064#74064):

> We now sort the gen-u-wine sites list by the amount of reputation you have on each site.

However, that's not the case on the StackExchange.com homepage. There, the site are listed in random order rather than being listed by my reputation total on each site.

The list is ordered properly on other sites though.

Comment: Apparently, this has been [around for a while](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66360/stack-exchange-sites-list-pop-up-order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gen-u-wine sites lists are now sorted by reputation on [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) and [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com). As with the rest of the network, you must have at least 200 rep on a site for it to appear in non-random order.

Comment: Yay! Thanks. This was driving me nuts.