# Indicate which sites in Stack Exchange I belong to in the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

As the Stack Exchange family of sites grows bigger every day, I find it difficult to quickly find those sites that I care most about in the Stack Exchange menu at the top of all the sites.

I'd like some kind of indication (perhaps highlighted, or an icon) on that menu, so I can find more quickly.

I'm guessing that the pulldown was originally intended to allow you to navigate at a glance, but as it grows more complex, it becomes much more difficult.

**Edit**
Based on @Grace's response below, I believe that one possibility is to add a "My Sites" submenu next to the "All Sites" submenu.  I realize the benefit of having all sites listed, but sometimes I just want to get in to do what I need, and get out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *some* level of indication, but not visual and only if you participate heavily in all of the sites you want to see. Any sites which you have at least 200 reputation on are always at the top of the list in the dropdown up there. These are also sorted by how much reputation you have on them. So it'll reduce the amount of sites you'll have to sift through to find them (down specifically to only them), provided you get enough reputation in all of your beloved sites.

Some kind of indication of the sub-200 sites might be nice, just to cut down on the time of hunting and pecking. I wouldn't mind icons, but at the point that we start marking the sub-200 sites, it may be simply more preferable to just include them in the top-level sorting anyway.

Comment: What about simply adding a "My Sites" submenu, in addition to the "All Sites"?  I realize the benefit of being able to see all the sites, but sometimes I just want to do what I need to do and get out.

Comment: @Wonko I know exactly what you mean. It's troublesome to find Writers and RPG for me. As it were, there *was* a request for a "My Sites" section or similar such. The [implementation for this was actually the sorting that I describe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69047/tab-showing-only-my-sites-in-the-stackexchange-global-inbox). See also [a similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72438/can-we-get-a-favorite-site-link-box-somewhere).

Comment: I was editing my post as you posted this.  I agree that the sorting helps, but as the list grows and grows (and from the looks of Area 51, it is going to continue to do so), that is still unwieldy and may "need" to be revisited.

Answer (score 0):

`Wonko the Sane` is right.
Last time I've noticed that when I access every StackExchange I am automatically logged in there. It's a bit confusing when I have some question in some of them and in excess of it I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

In your user profile, there is an **Accounts** tab in which you can associate all your SE sites to which you are a member.

You can use this if you really want to navigate to other SE sites in which you are a member already.

Comment: Oh, navigating to the other sites isn't a problem.  It's just that there are now more than 3 dozen sites listed in the SE button, and there is no indication as to which I am associated and which I am not.